# Constructor issue with GridView and ArrayList

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, constructor, bitmap

Hey guys I have this error message and I dont understand it !

" The constructor ClipData.Item(Bitmap) is undefined "

Here is my code :

```
 package com.example.hellogridview;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.ClipData.Item;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.widget.GridView;
/**
  * 
  * @author manish.s
 *
 */

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView gridView;
 ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



 //set grid view item
 Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.blue);
 Bitmap userIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.green);

 gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon));
 gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon));


  gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_row, gridArray);
  gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
 }

}
```

The error message takes place on this two lines :

```
 gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon));
 gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon));
```

How to add aconstructor for ClipData.Item ?

Thanks everybody !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `ClipData.Item` with a `Bitmap` object.

`ClipData.Item` supports `CharSequence`, `String`, `Intent` and `Uri`.

You can check out the different constructors [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.Item.html).

Your best option would be to save the `Bitmap` to disk and get its respective `Uri`.

If the `Bitmap` is very small you might get away with encoding it to `Base64` and saving it as a `String`.

Edit: Since your Bitmaps are from drawable resource files, you can get the `Uri`using the below code:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.hellogridview/" 
                  + R.drawable.blue);
ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(imageUri);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot benito ! But I dont even have an idea of how to do it =p ! My bitmap is very very small indeed, can you help me to implement your method and pass the bitmap into the array ? Thanks again !